# Why my SQLite request in java code output only months from October(&&/10/&&)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, query-string

Case: In my SQLite database date store as DATE type. Iam trying to show records from current month and if that month is 10, 11 or 12 everything is working but month from 1 to 9 is giving empty output.

'''

```
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
    int yearNumber = ld.getYear();
    int monthNumber = ld.getMonth().getValue();

    String queryString = "SELECT " +
            " *, " +
            "strftime('%m', DAY_DATE) as Month, " +   //  getting number of month from 01 to 12 
            "strftime('%Y', DAY_DATE) as Year   " +   // getting number of year
            " FROM " + DAYS_TABLE +
            " WHERE "+"Month" +
            " LIKE "  + monthNumber +
            " AND " + "Year"+
            " LIKE " + yearNumber +
            " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_DAY_DATE +
            " DESC " ;
```

'''

What should i use to see records from each month?

Comment: Have you tried to replace `LIKE` by `=` in the `WHERE` condition?

Comment: There is no DATE data type in SQLite even if you define it as such. What is important is the format of the dates. Is the format that you save in the table `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work even with 10th, 11th, 12th month.

Comment: @forpas Format is "yyyy-MM-dd", is this ok?

Comment: Yes it is ok. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `strftime()` returns a string and not a number, so `strftime('%m', DAY_DATE)` may return `05` and not `5`.
If you want to compare it with a number you must convert it and this can be done implicitly by adding `0`. 
So change to:

```
 " WHERE (Month + 0) = "  + monthNumber +
 " AND (Year + 0) = " + yearNumber +
 " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_DAY_DATE +
 " DESC " ;
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you. I cant understand why is it working like that but it's working!